# unix uncompress multiple gz and save in particular directory

Tags: files, gzip

I have a directory with thousands of files .gz and I would like to uncompress and save the uncompressed files in a specific directory.

I have tried but I can get it (beginner in this field).

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit your question to include more information on _how_ you want to accomplish the task. Are you looking for a console- or GUI-based approach? Is there only _one_ target directory, or one per `.gz` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
mkdir destination
cd destination
for g in ../origin/*.gz; do      # Each *.gz file in origin...
   gzcat $g > ${g##../origin/}   # ... gets uncompressed to here
done
```

With thousands of files, the glob (`../origin/*.gz`) might choke... and the destination directory might also get very slow.